# I am having problem with this error: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.ForceMode2D' to 'UnityEngine.ForceMode'. Please Help Me solve it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Currently I am working on a game via Unity3d. I have to jump my character with impulse on the ground. I am using the command I am learning from Youtube. Everything seems fine in the Teacher's game , but mine is not working. Please help me why it is not working?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [SerializeField]
    private float Moveforce = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpforce = 11f;

    private float Movementx;

    private Rigidbody mybody;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    private Animator anim;
    private string WALK_ANIMATION = "Walk";

    private void Awake()
    {
        mybody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

   

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PlayerMoveKeyboard();
        AnimatePlayer();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerJump();
    }

  

    void PlayerJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            mybody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpforce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Youre using the 3d rigidbody. Not 2d. Which is the correct one?

Comment: Okay, I got the problem, by mistake I took Rigidbody component rather than RgiBody2D.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2D & 3D functions.

### 2D

```
private Rigidbody2D mybody;

...

mybody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpforce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

### 3D

```
private Rigidbody mybody;

...

mybody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpforce, 0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
```